# Umbraco 6 - internal hyperlinks are not rendering

Tags: html, hyperlink, umbraco

I'm working on the current Umbraco release (v6.1.6). I have a dev site which I'm publishing to the staging server using Umbraco's Courier tool.

On the dev site I have pages which link to other pages in the CMS by using the 'Insert Link' option in the page editor's context menu, and they generate anchor tags with an `href` attribute of the form `href="/{localLink:2122}"` which something renders to friendly urls on the front-end.

However, after `Courier`ing pages to the staging site using Courier I find that the hyperlinks' hrefs aren't being rendered correctly and retain the `href="/{localLink:uvwxyz}"` value. I have logged into back-office on the staging server and re-inserted the hyperlink and they are correctly rendered, with the href values being converted to the corresponding friendly URL.

Other details: both installs, dev and staging are v.6.1.6 although the staging site was a clean install while the dev was upgraded from 4.6 to 6.1. Courier is version 2.5 which is appropriate for Umbraco v.6 and everything has been installed via Courier's package manager.

I'm not sure what is causing this (or not causing the friendly URLs to appear) Googling has led me to a couple of questions on the Umbraco dev site but they all suggest the issue was fixed in v.6.1.6 ...

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you suspect this is a bug, then you should raise this with the Umbraco/Courier team or on the Umbraco forum. Since this is a paid-for module, you should get a response fairly quickly.

Comment: I'm not sure its an issue with Courier or Umbraco. I've found Umbraco pretty frustrating and surprisingly unfinished in places. Re-publishing the entire site seems to fix these issues about 80% of the time, but this is hardly conducive to building up affection for the CMS.

Comment: We've had some help from a consultancy specialising in Umbraco. They have over a hundred deployments under their belts and they advised us to steer clear of Courier wherever possible as it continues to be buggy and unpolished. Having spent a quarter of a year on this stuff I'm inclined to agree.